# No response from Ratchet websocket using Apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache, websocket, cakephp-3.0, reverse-proxy, ratchet

I am trying to implement [WyriHaximus/Ratchet](https://github.com/WyriHaximus/Ratchet) plugin for CakePHP 3.
My cakephp app is running on eg: blah.myhost.com which has a ssl certificate enabled.
I've setup my app.php for the plugins configuration like this

```php
'WyriHaximus' => [
        'Ratchet' => [
            'internal' => [
                'address' => '0.0.0.0',
                'port' => 8888,
            ],
            'external' => [
                'hostname' => 'blah.myhost.com',
                'port' => 8888,
            ],
            'defaults' => [
                'retry_delay_growth' => 0.25,
            ],
            'realm_salt' => 'y[Pw3^o`hLxn`sZkZgtIZ={?B:!Q.8',
            'realm_auth_key_salt' => 'EEA~D`o:ZIIm=hR0bcD$3D+((ti:V;',
            'realms' => [
                'realm1' => [], // Always has to be an array
                'secure' => [
                    'auth' => true,
                    'auth_key' => '5J^e=7ec5g!0j#I4.t%"0Ih2)qp]I)',
                    'max_retries' => 13,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]
```

and I can run the web socket server with the instructions [here](https://github.com/WyriHaximus/Ratchet/blob/master/docs/shell.md) which runs fine and outputs this

```
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6496330 debug      [Thruway\Peer\Router 5123] New router created
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6531680 info       [Thruway\Authentication\AuthenticationManager 5123] New client created
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6550820 info       [WyriHaximus\Ratchet\Websocket\InternalClient 5123] New client created
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6554090 info       [WyriHaximus\Ratchet\Websocket\InternalClient 5123] New client created
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6560020 info       [WyriHaximus\Ratchet\Security\AuthorizationManager 5123] New client created
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6614470 info       [WyriHaximus\Ratchet\Security\JWTAuthProvider 5123] New client created
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6619220 info       [Thruway\Peer\Router 5123] Starting router
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6685010 info       [Thruway\RealmManager 5123] Got prehello...
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6687590 debug      [Thruway\RealmManager 5123] Creating new realm 'thruway.auth'
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6719630 debug      [Thruway\RealmManager 5123] Adding realm 'thruway.auth'
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6763120 debug      [Thruway\Authentication\AuthenticationManager 5123] Client onMessage: [Thruway\Message\WelcomeMessage]
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6765620 info       [Thruway\Authentication\AuthenticationManager 5123] We have been welcomed...
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6794560 debug      [Thruway\Authentication\AuthenticationManager 5123] Client onMessage: [Thruway\Message\RegisteredMessage]
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6797150 info       [Thruway\Role\Callee 5123] Setting registration_id for thruway.auth.registermethod (0)
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6814840 info       [Thruway\RealmManager 5123] Got prehello...
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6817350 debug      [Thruway\RealmManager 5123] Creating new realm 'realm1'
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6819770 debug      [Thruway\RealmManager 5123] Adding realm 'realm1'
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6825430 debug      [WyriHaximus\Ratchet\Websocket\InternalClient 5123] Client onMessage: [Thruway\Message\WelcomeMessage]
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6827820 info       [WyriHaximus\Ratchet\Websocket\InternalClient 5123] We have been welcomed...
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6835090 info       [Thruway\RealmManager 5123] Got prehello...
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6837500 debug      [Thruway\RealmManager 5123] Creating new realm 'secure'
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6839950 debug      [Thruway\RealmManager 5123] Adding realm 'secure'
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6845380 debug      [WyriHaximus\Ratchet\Websocket\InternalClient 5123] Client onMessage: [Thruway\Message\WelcomeMessage]
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6847750 info       [WyriHaximus\Ratchet\Websocket\InternalClient 5123] We have been welcomed...
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6852190 info       [Thruway\RealmManager 5123] Got prehello...
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6856620 debug      [WyriHaximus\Ratchet\Security\AuthorizationManager 5123] Client onMessage: [Thruway\Message\WelcomeMessage]
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6858990 info       [WyriHaximus\Ratchet\Security\AuthorizationManager 5123] We have been welcomed...
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6875670 info       [Thruway\Transport\RatchetTransportProvider 5123] Websocket listening on 0.0.0.0:8888
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6888710 info       [Thruway\RealmManager 5123] Got prehello...
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6893150 debug      [WyriHaximus\Ratchet\Security\JWTAuthProvider 5123] Client onMessage: [Thruway\Message\WelcomeMessage]
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6895540 info       [WyriHaximus\Ratchet\Security\JWTAuthProvider 5123] We have been welcomed...
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6899420 debug      [WyriHaximus\Ratchet\Security\JWTAuthProvider 5123] Client onMessage: [Thruway\Message\RegisteredMessage]
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6901870 info       [Thruway\Role\Callee 5123] Setting registration_id for thruway.auth.jwt.onhello (0)
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6906900 debug      [WyriHaximus\Ratchet\Security\JWTAuthProvider 5123] Client onMessage: [Thruway\Message\RegisteredMessage]
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6909310 info       [Thruway\Role\Callee 5123] Setting registration_id for thruway.auth.jwt.onauthenticate (1)
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6928160 debug      [Thruway\Authentication\AuthenticationManager 5123] Client onMessage: [Thruway\Message\InvocationMessage]
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6937120 debug      [WyriHaximus\Ratchet\Security\JWTAuthProvider 5123] Client onMessage: [Thruway\Message\ResultMessage]
2019-06-04T18:38:02.6942790 debug      [WyriHaximus\Ratchet\Security\JWTAuthProvider 5123] Authentication Method Registration Successful: jwt
```

my ufw status outputs this

```
:~# ufw status |  grep 8888
8888/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
8888/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

my Apache default-ssl.conf for the ProxyPass part looks like this

```
SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass "/wss2/" "wss://blah.myhost.com:8888/"
```

This is the code I'm running in the browser to attempt to connect to the websocket.

```js
var conn = new WebSocket('wss://blah.myhost.com/wss2/');
conn.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("Connection established!");
};

conn.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
};
```

I get this message in the apache access.log but no error

```
04/Jun/2019:17:47:56 +1200] "GET /wss2/ HTTP/1.1" 500 4577 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
```

The response I get after a long time in the browser is this

```js
WebSocket connection to 'wss://blah.myhost.com/wss2/' failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out
```

Other methods I've tried include
Using Rewrite engine in my Apache default-ssl.conf

```
SSLProxyEngine On
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
RewriteRule ^/    wss://blah.myhost.com:8888/ [P,L]
```

Using this to connect

```
var conn = new WebSocket('wss://blah.myhost.com/');
```

This gives the exact same response

Also when I change the app.php config to use the external ip 0.0.0.0 to make the server listen on 0.0.0.0:8888 and then Rewrite to  wss://0.0.0.0:8888/ I get this error on apache error.log when trying to connect.

```
[Tue Jun 04 18:27:04.089837 2019] [proxy:error] [pid 5648] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): [client ^^^.^^^.^^^.^:^^^^] AH01084: pass request body failed to 0.0.0.0:8888 (0.0.0.0)
[Tue Jun 04 18:27:04.090047 2019] [proxy:error] [pid 5648] [client ^^^.^^^.^^^.^:^^^^] AH00898: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server returned by /
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong; perhaps my config in app.php is wrong, or I'm missing some vital steps.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using a [autobahn](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-js-browser) to connect to the Websocket instead of the code I provided. Also I changed my external IP in my app.php to 0.0.0.0 and the Proxypass ip to 0.0.0.0 instead of my domain name.